# Using a array with sumifs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

The purpose of this formula is to sum the values in K if values from column B are 20x, 200, 702, 201 and also if values in column E is only IS and also values in column L read dam. I am receiving a value of 0 and I know that the value is more than 0 I think it's my array that I am not using correctly. Below is my formula I'm currently using and a screenshot of the data.

```
=SUMIFS($K$2:$K$5000,$B$2:$B$5000,"*20X*","200","702","201"},$E$2:$E$5000,"IS",$L$2:$L$5000,"*dam*")
```

[image: DATA]

[image]

Comment: wrap it in a SUM(): `=SUM(SUMIFS($K$2:$K$5000,$B$2:$B$5000,"*20X*","200","702","201"},$E$2:$E$5000,"IS",$L$2:$L$5000,"*dam*"))`

Comment: @ScottCraner damn you're good with these formulas

Comment: @ScottCraner tried that and it still showing a zero value

Comment: @Luis I tried `=SUM(SUMIFS($K$2:$K$5000,$B$2:$B$5000,{"20X","200","702","201"},$E$2:$E$5000,"IS",$L$2:$L$5000,"dam"))` without the wild-card `*` , and it worked for me

Comment: @ShaiRado I added a second snapshot with the formula suggested and you can see a value of 0 it sill happening

Comment: @Luis in the sample of data you provided I don't see any matches. I don't see any "IS" in Column E, or any "dam" in Column L. are you sure you have any ?

Comment: @ShaiRado I should probably call it a day your right I just filtered and none were found. Good Call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be problems copying the formula from the Comments.  This works:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($K$2:$K$5000,$B$2:$B$5000,{"*20X*","200","702","201"},$E$2:$E$5000,"IS",$L$2:$L$5000,"*dam*"))
```

[image]